# How could I print the return numbers instead if alpha

Tags: java, oop, exception, methods, return

I want to test program that prompts the user to enter a letter grade and displays the quality points by calling the above method in a try-catch block.

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.lang.model.util.ElementScanner14;

public class Lab17 {
    public static int qualityPoint(String alpha) {
        if (alpha.equals("A+"))
            return 4;
        else if (alpha.equals("A"))
            return (int) 3.75;
        else if (alpha.equals("B+"))
            return (int) 3.5;
        else if (alpha.equals("B"))
            return 3;
        else if (alpha.equals("C+"))
            return (int) 2.5;
        else if (alpha.equals("C"))
            return 2;
        else if (alpha.equals("D+"))
            return (int) 1.5;
        else if (alpha.equals("D"))
            return 1;
        else if (alpha.equals("F"))
            return 0;
        else
            throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid grade");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a letter grade: ");
        String alpha = sc.next();
        try {
            int res = qualityPoint(alpha);
            System.out.println("The quality points " + alpha);
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: Enter just a letter grade");
        }

    }
}
```

Enter a letter grade:
A
The quality points A

I want the output to be
Enter a letter grade:
A
The quality points A
or
Enter a letter grade:
x
Invalid grade

Answer (score 0):

You can mistake it, use res instead of alpha.

```
int res = qualityPoint(alpha);
System.out.println("The quality points " + res);
```